# Orbeon: readony instance affecting the form links depending on the position in the model with respect to other instances

Tags: orbeon, xforms

I have come across a strange defect. I am using Orbeon 3.9 CE on Tomcat. Depending on the text-field value='true' the link will be shown as in the screenshot. Please note the trigger refer to "data-safe" instance for showing and hiding.

```
<xforms:trigger appearance="minimal" ref=".[instance('data-safe')/data-safe='true']">
    <xforms:label>
        Add
    </xforms:label>
</xforms:trigger>
```

This is how the screen should look like.
[image: expected functionality]

Now, for as part of performance improvements, i have one of the instance with the attribute `xxforms:readonly="true"`

[image: 1st instance read-only]

Here the 1st instance is readonly

then the form displayed changes to like below. where the add link is disabled. 
[image: add link disabled]

now if i change the order of the readonly instance from 1st position in the model to somewhere below. like shown 
[image: readonly moved below]

the add link gets enabled 
[image: expected functionality]

here is a code sample to explain the issue

```
  <xhtml:head>

    <xhtml:title>SO question</xhtml:title>
    <!-- CSS StyleSheet test-->

    <!-- Link to the Model goes Here -->
    <!-- Needs exslt to do some fancy things with Dates and Time -->
    <xforms:model id="model">

        <!-- -->
        <!-- Places Instances Here -->
        <!-- -->


        <xforms:instance id="dropdown-values"   src="oxf:/apps/TSDM/global_instances/Dropdown-Values.xml" xxforms:readonly="true"/>

        <xforms:instance id="form-attributes">
            <attributes>
                <form-global>
                    <current-page>1</current-page> <!-- Always starts on 1 -->
                    <previous-page></previous-page> <!-- Always starts on 1 -->
                    <next-page></next-page> <!-- Always starts on 1 -->
                    <first-page>1</first-page> <!-- First Page Boundary: 1 always -->
                    <last-page>12</last-page> <!-- Last Page Boundary: Change based on form -->
                    <summary>false</summary> <!-- Enable Summary View indicator -->
                </form-global>
            </attributes>
        </xforms:instance>

        <xforms:instance id="data-safe">
            <flag>
                <data-safe>true</data-safe>
                <data-safe1></data-safe1>
            </flag>
        </xforms:instance>

    <xforms:bind id="group-level-specifications-credit-effective-end-date" nodeset="instance('data-safe')/data-safe"
                    calculate="."
                    readonly="false()"/>


    <!--xforms:bind nodeset="instance('data-safe')/data-safe1" type="xforms:date"
                    calculate="months(xforms:dayTimeDuration(../data-safe))"
                    readonly="false()"/-->

    </xforms:model>


</xhtml:head>
<!-- End of Head -->



<!-- Start of the Body of the Page -->
<xhtml:body class="MainBODY">

    <xforms:switch>
        <xforms:case>
            <xforms:trigger appearance="minimal" ref=".[instance('data-safe')/data-safe='true']">
                <xforms:label>
                    Add
                </xforms:label>

            </xforms:trigger>
        </xforms:case>
    </xforms:switch>
    <xforms:input ref="instance('data-safe')/data-safe" />
    <br/>
    <xforms:input ref="instance('data-safe')/data-safe1" />


</xhtml:body>
```

Comment: @KaipaMSarma i think it is a orbeon bug. So I dont think xforms tag is needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write `<xforms:trigger ref=".[some condition]">`, you are not only hiding the trigger when the condition is false, you are also binding it to whatever node `.` points to. Unless your trigger is inside some container element (`<xforms:group>`, …) which changes the context, the context is the root element of the first instance. When a trigger is bound to a node:

1. The trigger won't show if the node is non-relevant.
2. The trigger shows as disabled if the node is read-only.

You are in this second case, not because of an `<xforms:bind readonly="false()"/>` in your code, but because when you put an `xxforms:readonly="true"` on an instance, all its nodes are marked as readonly.

The solution in your case is simple: move that instance as the second one, as you did, or bind the trigger to another node that isn't read-only by using another XPath expression instead of `.`.

Comment: u didnt understand my question correctly. the trigger is not bound to that read-only instance. but an instance after that the readonly instance in the model. and depending on the position of the readonly instance, the triggers bound with other instances are behaving as readonly. please see the screenshot

Comment: @NaveenBabu Could you edit your question to include a minimal example  that I can run here to reproduce this?

Comment: the code sample is already there, as the last part of the question under "here is a code sample to explain the issue"

Comment: @NaveenBabu Ah, sorry, I didn't see it was a complete example. I got it running, and see the trigger a readonly. But this is because it is bound to the first instance, which is readonly. Change `.` with `instance('form-attributes')` so it's bound to the second instance, which isn't readonly, and the trigger won't show as disabled.

Comment: the common syntax was `<xforms:trigger ref=".[some condition]">` but as per your comment, can we change the syntax as `<xforms:trigger appearance="minimal" ref="<condition>">` as this code works fine `<xforms:trigger appearance="minimal" ref="instance('data-safe')/data-safe='true'">`. I want to circulate the syntax to my team so that this issue can be avoided. Moreover is the issue pointed out, a defect in orbeon? As the order of the instance position in model is affecting the functionality.

Comment: I don't think I managed to make it clear what `ref=".[<condition>]"` does. It doesn't tell the XForms engine "show the trigger only of `<condition>` is true". Or at least not directly. `ref` binds the trigger to a node and that node is obtained by the XForms engine by evaluating the XPath expression. The XPath expression `.[<condition>]` means "the current node if `<condition>` is met, otherwise nothing (the empty sequence)".

Comment: And if you bind a control to "nothing", then that control is not shown, per the XForms spec. So you are either binding the trigger to the current node, if `<condition>` is true, or to nothing which hides the control, if `<condition>` is false. Does it make sense so far?

Comment: If this made sense, I guess you are seeing now why if `<condition>` is true and the current node is read-only, then the trigger becomes "read-only", i.e. gets shows as disabled. Now if instead of writing `ref=".[<condition>]"` you write `ref="<condition>"`, the XPath expression will always return a value; it will never return an empty sequence, and so the trigger will always be displayed.

Comment: You could return a value which isn't the current node if `<condition>` is met and an empty sequence when it isn't with something like: `ref="if (<condition>) then 42 else ()`, with 42 being a dummy value. You can maybe use `true()` instead of 42 so it looks a bit less strange.